# Replace all hyphen types by the ascii hyphen "-"

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, hyphenation

Is there a way to replace all types of hyphens by the simple ASCII `'-'`? I am looking for something like this that works for spaces:

```py
txt = re.sub(r'[\s]+',' ',txt)
```

I believe that some non-ASCII `'-'` hyphens are avoiding the correct process of removing some specific stopwords (name of projects that are connected by hyphens).

I want to replace this AR–L1003' for instance by AR-L1003, but I want to do this for the entire text.

Comment: Can you share a sample of the data that you wish to replace and the expected result?

Comment: Why don't you look up all the hyphen characters that exist (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen#Unicode) and put them in a regex `[ ]+`?

Comment: @trincot Yes, that was my question. I wonder if there is like \s a way to identify all hyphens! Maybe there is not!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just list those hyphens in a class. Here is one possible list -- extend it to your needs:

```
txt = re.sub(r'[‐᠆﹣－⁃−]+','-',txt)
```

The standard `re` library does not support the `\p` syntax for matching unicode categories, but if you can import `regex`, then it is possible:

```
import regex

txt = regex.sub(r'\p{Pd}+', '-', txt)
```

Comment: Will `regex` replace `re`?

Comment: See [Add support for Matthew Barnett python regex module](https://github.com/firasdib/Regex101/issues/440). Also read Guido van Rossum speak on the subject [back in 2011](http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/Should-we-move-to-replace-re-with-regex-td1857882.html)