# Replace all the types of newline characters by "\n" in python

Tags: regex, python-3.x, newline

Is there a way to replace all types of the character newline in python by "\n"? The most common newline characters seem to be "\n" and "\r" but in [wikepedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) you can find different representations. I am looking for something like:

For whitespaces (using re):

```
txt = re.sub(r'[\s]+',' ',txt)
```

For hyphens (using regex).. See reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53750961/replace-all-hyphen-types-by-the-ascii-hyphen):

```
txt = regex.sub(r'\p{Pd}+', '-', txt)
```

Comment: What is your question? Is it to normailze text or to replace newline characters only?

Comment: Try `regex.sub(r'\R', '\n', s)`

Comment: Just to replace newline characters. I will remove the last line since it may be causing ambiquity.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your answer is great and it works very well. However, although I have been using regex as above to normalize different types of hyphens, regex.sub(r'\R', '\n', s) didnt work for me in this case!

Comment: This is almost a dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388630/unicode-regexp-to-match-line-breaks

Comment: Two more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445326/regex-in-java-how-to-deal-with-newline/3445417#3445417 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40928114/simple-regex-working-on-windows-and-not-in-linux-using-java

Comment: @revo Sorry. I was looking (maybe) for a simpler python solution (using python modules). In the end, the final solution is close to the java one or general one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a `\R` construct that you may use in Python PyPi regex module. However, even with `re`, you may use its equivalent:

```
re.sub(r'\u000D\u000A|[\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0085\u2028\u2029]', '\n', s)
```

See the [Python demo](https://rextester.com/GAR74004).

Answer (score 1):

To replace any `\r` (carriage return) by `\n` (new line)  :

```
txt = re.sub(r"\r", "\n", txt)
```

`r` before double quote means raw string to escape the slash.